# Detecting jump gesture with Kinect [Algo]

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, kinect, openni

I am trying to implement jump as well as ducking gestures of a user, and I am using Kinect for skeleton tracking and extracting the joint positions. I previously implemented a rudimentary algorithm taking the history of past 10 values of a joint and checking if the joint moved upward/downward greater than a threshold to deduce a jump/duck.

However, that doesn't seem to be the correct approach since the user:
- might duck a little before jumping
- when user jumps, also comes down and a duck is deduced.
- when the user ducks, also comes up, a jump is deduced
- the user when ducking might stay longer in air than when he ducks or sits down.

What would be an appropriate algorithm to detect both of these jump/duck gestures in a robust manner with Kinect joints being retrieved instantaneously?

Comment: Have you looked into [Kinect Toolbox](http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/) or the [Fizbin Kinect Gesture Library](https://github.com/EvilClosetMonkey/Fizbin.Kinect.Gestures) as possible gesture recognition solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I think detecting jumps it's not easy to make a efficient algorithm for that in a easy way. It's a complex movement to detect that why you must use something robust. There are four types of approach when it comes to detect movements:

- **Basic gesture recognition** -simple movement like clapping hands measuring the distance between them. When the distance is 0 the movement its performed
- **An algorithmic approach** - more complex movement where you have to validate the initial position, verification if the movement is being correctly performed, and then verify final position
- **Weight-network approach** - this one can use neural networks to detect movements
- **Template-Based approach** - You can record a movement and then using template matching algorithms like **dynamic time Warping** to check if the movement performed by the user and the movement record are equal

You have to be careful which approach to use because sometimes this algorithms are a cocktail of mathematical operations and you must choose the one approach that is more efficient to your case. There is a way of detect jumps using the **Weight-network** approach and neural networks although i never seen one. there is a book called **Kinect for Windows SDK Programming Guide** there it's explained how to detect jumps using **Weight-network** approach and neural networks.